# Is it possible to dynamically generate summary from the description attribute

Tags: c#

This might be me asking for a pink unicorn, but still thought doesn't hurt to ask.

I have an enumeration with description attribute set. Is it possible to assign the message of description attribute as summary? The reason is that it helps with intellisense when using the enum member. Currently I am just duplicating the summary and the description.

```
public enum UserMessageId
{

    /// <summary>
    /// "This is a sample description."
    /// </summary>
    [Description("This is a sample description.")]    
    E0,
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't believe you could do this without some sort of plugin. The summary tag is just a comment

Comment: As @amura.cxg says, this is not possible and I am not aware of any tools that do it for you.

Comment: IT is easier to go the otherway sometimes, where and why do you use the description attribute? There are some injection techniques that you can use but we need to identify the path of least resistance here first.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input, I did know it was asking for too much. :) 
@ChrisSchaller: I am using description to log the message, whenever that enum member is being passed to a method.

Comment: Awesome, post your code that does that, we'll give you alternate code that reads from the XML doc comment file as part of the build. I use this a lot in web service documentation, and to show better descriptions when binding enums to combo boxes, certainly beats defining the description twice in code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know some shorcuts which allow to do this directly (your wish is pretty weird for me). But for example, you can use following trick (it implies usage of `git`). As I remember, `git` allows you to run custom script for file every time it was modified. It allows you to modify content of file. All you need is to write following templated summaries

```
/// <summary>
/// %DESCRIPTION MACRO%
/// <summary>
[Description %PLACE TO INSERT DESCRIPTION MACRO%]
```

Your script will process such macro in your way. Sorry for absent more detailed technical information, hope it will help. Also you can change script, every time it finds %Some Macro%, it automatically inserts `Description` attribute after comments at new line. But anyway some parsing is needed